# How to find the count of numbers that are less than each element of a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`, for each element in the list, I need to find the count of a number of elements that are less than the number. For example, the first element is 1 and there are 0 elements in the list that are less than 1, the second number is 2 and there is 1 element less than 2. So basically the output should be `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Need to do this in Python. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code I've tried,

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
count = 0
final = []
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(lst)):
        if lst[i] < lst[j]:
            count = count + 1
    final.append(count)
print (final)
```

Below is the output I got,

```
[6, 11, 15, 18, 20, 21, 21]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

out = [sum(vv < v for vv in lst[:i]) for i, v in enumerate(lst)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: So you're assuming that their list is sorted but  could have duplicates?

Comment: @KellyBundy No, I'm not assuming the list is sorted. It's just counting number of lesser elements to actual index.

Comment: But if it's not sorted, then your counts are too low. For example for [5,4] you compute [0,0] instead of [1,0].

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah, I see your point. Yes, in that case it won't work. But OP accepted the answer so the solution might be what he wanted. If not, I can provide updated answer.